# Aw, snap error in chrome while insert value into web sql using executeSql

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, google-chrome

I am creating a sqlite editor for android application, it is execute correctly still yesterday and finally just I tried to backup the chrome websql db so just copy the files from the following path "C:\Users\merbin.SERVER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\databases" and "C:\Users\merbin.SERVER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\System Profile\databases". Today I got the Aw, snap error on chrome, I debug the error and found, the error occur when I trying to create a table or inserting data into the database. But select query is execute perfectly. Some code examples are

```
    query="insert into tbl(Type) values('Test')";
 insert_query(query,insert_success,insert_fail);

    function insert_query(query,succ_fun,fail_fun)
{
  db.transaction(function(tx,result)
  {
    tx.executeSql(query, [],
    function(tx,result)
    {
        eval(succ_fun)(result)
    });
  },eval(fail_fun));
}

function insert_success(result)
{
    debugger;
    $("#ex_area").empty();
    $("#ex_area").append(result.rowsAffected+" Row(s) Affected.<br> Last Inserted ID is "+result.insertId);
    alert("Insert Success");

    return false;

}
function insert_fail(result)
{
    debugger;
    $("#ex_area").empty();
    $("#ex_area").append("<span class='error'>"+result.message+"<br> Code : "+result.code+"</span>");

}
```

After that "eval(succ_fun)(result)" line I getting the Aw, snap error. screenshot is shown below.
[image 1 Error on the Next Line Execution Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3GD9.png)
[image 2 From previous line I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGmFk.png)

**Note :** I think after update the chrome I have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem running the code through **localserver**. First the chrome allow to access the websql without using any server, but recent update chrome has change that rule. So must need any local server like xampp,wamp,IIS or etc...

Answer (score 0):

by running the code through localserver: your JavaScript hosted through local server or the database or both

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Google Chrome shortcut on your desktop.

Right click it, then click properties.

Add -allow-file-access-from-files to the end of the Target.

The end of the target should look like this:
\chrome.exe" -allow-file-access-from-files

Go into Task Manager.

Click Details.

End every single chrome.exe which is running.

Open up Google Chrome using the new shortcut you created.

Open up your website which uses WebSQL.

This worked for me.

Warning:
-allow-file-access-from-files lets Google Chrome have access to all of the files on your computer. ONLY, ONLY use this shortcut for developing. Do not browser the web, especially to untrusted websites, while you have this feature activated.

To deactivate it:
Go into task manager and end all chrome.exe's then open up chrome with a normal shortcut.

Comment: It is not working, please check the below image is it right or not https://s31.postimg.org/u5y85impn/websql_error.jpg

Comment: Yea that looks correct. It didn't work for my girlfriend either, but we found out later it was because she hadn't exited all the chrome.exe's properly.

Did you go into task manager and make sure all chrome.exe's were gone?